# How to find element in array

Tags: javascript

I'm really new to javascript and I have an array of objects.

```
var cart = [
  { id: 1, price: 2 },
  { id: 2, price: 1 }
];
```

and I'm using a for loop to find the ID:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
  if (cart[i].id === id) {
    return cart[i]
  }
}

return null;
```

I know there's functions like `find()`, but I'm not too sure on how to use that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [find](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp), you might need [babel](https://babeljs.io/), but just the code you need:

`ES6`

```
const id = 1;
const found = cart.find(item => item.id === id)
```

`Vanilla`

```
var id = 1;
var found = cart.find(function(item) {return item.id === id})
```

`find` takes a function (in our case with es6: `() => {}` is an anonymous function), and applies it to every item in the list, until it finds the first match, how does it know when it is a match: once your function returns true, then it cuts the loop, and returns the item.

**HOWEVER**

Another option, that does not use find but might be more readable than a traditional for loop:

```
var id = 1;
for(var item in cart) {
  if(item.id == id) {
    return item;
  }
}
return null
```

There are also a slew of libraries out there that can help you achieve this on different ways, ex: [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), [lodash](https://lodash.com/), which I will not cover, but you can take a look at if you are really interested.

Answer (score 4):

You are right.  There is a function called [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).  You can set up the callback function to use with `find`, and even set it up to accept a parameter (such as the `id`):

```js
var cart = [{
  id: 1,
  price: 2
}, {
  id: 2,
  price: 1
}];

function byID(id) {
  return function(element) {
    return element.id == id;
  }
}

var item = cart.find(byID(2));

console.log(item);
```

With issues like this, I very much appreciate the library [lodash](https://lodash.com/).  It allows you to do things like so:

```js
var cart = [{id: 1, price: 5}, {id: 2, price: 6}];

var item = _.find(cart, {id:2});

console.log(item);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```